# Get combinations of list without replacement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of people and I want to make all combinations of their teams (of 3) with each other.

```
list_of_ppl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

What i need is:

```
>>> [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]
>>> [['A','B','D'],['C','E','F']]
>>> [['A','B','E'],['C','D','F']]
>>> [['A','B','F'],['C','D','E']]
>>> [['A','C','E'],['B','D','F']]
>>> and so on...
```

**Edit:** The len(list_of_ppl) can be greater than 6 and can be a number that is not divisible by 3. I only want teams of `3`

For eg:

```
list_of_ppl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
>>> [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G']]
>>> [['A','B','D'],['C','E','G'],['F']]
>>> [['A','B','D'],['C','F','G'],['E']]
>>> [['A','B','F'],['C','E','G'],['D']]
>>> [['A','E','G'],['B','D','F'],['C']]
>>> and so on...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to keep getting a combination of 3 from the remaining list of people until the list is exhausted:

```
from itertools import combinations
def get_teams(list_of_ppl, size=3):
    if len(list_of_ppl) > size:
        for team in combinations(list_of_ppl, size):
            for teams in get_teams(list(set(list_of_ppl) - set(team))):
                yield [list(team), *teams]
    else:
        yield [list_of_ppl]
for team in get_teams(list_of_ppl):
    print(team)
```

so that with `list_of_ppl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']`, this outputs:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['F', 'E', 'D']]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['C', 'F', 'E']]
[['A', 'B', 'E'], ['C', 'F', 'D']]
[['A', 'B', 'F'], ['C', 'E', 'D']]
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['F', 'B', 'E']]
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['F', 'B', 'D']]
[['A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'E', 'D']]
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'B', 'F']]
[['A', 'D', 'F'], ['C', 'B', 'E']]
[['A', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'B', 'D']]
[['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'A']]
[['B', 'C', 'E'], ['F', 'A', 'D']]
[['B', 'C', 'F'], ['E', 'A', 'D']]
[['B', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'F', 'A']]
[['B', 'D', 'F'], ['C', 'A', 'E']]
[['B', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'A', 'D']]
[['C', 'D', 'E'], ['F', 'B', 'A']]
[['C', 'D', 'F'], ['E', 'B', 'A']]
[['C', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'A', 'D']]
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'B', 'A']]
```

or with a `list_of_ppl` whose length is not divisible by 3 such as `list_of_ppl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']`, this outputs:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['E', 'G', 'F'], ['D']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['E', 'G', 'D'], ['F']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'D'], ['G']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['G', 'F', 'D'], ['E']]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['E', 'C', 'G'], ['F']]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['E', 'C', 'F'], ['G']]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['E', 'G', 'F'], ['C']]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['C', 'G', 'F'], ['E']]
[['A', 'B', 'E'], ['C', 'G', 'F'], ['D']]
[['A', 'B', 'E'], ['C', 'G', 'D'], ['F']]
[['A', 'B', 'E'], ['C', 'F', 'D'], ['G']]
[['A', 'B', 'E'], ['G', 'F', 'D'], ['C']]
[['A', 'B', 'F'], ['E', 'C', 'G'], ['D']]
[['A', 'B', 'F'], ['E', 'C', 'D'], ['G']]
[['A', 'B', 'F'], ['E', 'G', 'D'], ['C']]
[['A', 'B', 'F'], ['C', 'G', 'D'], ['E']]
[['A', 'B', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'F'], ['D']]
[['A', 'B', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'D'], ['F']]
[['A', 'B', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'D'], ['C']]
[['A', 'B', 'G'], ['C', 'F', 'D'], ['E']]
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E', 'G'], ['F']]
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['G']]
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'G', 'F'], ['E']]
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'G', 'F'], ['B']]
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'G', 'F'], ['D']]
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'G', 'D'], ['F']]
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'F', 'D'], ['G']]
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['G', 'F', 'D'], ['B']]
[['A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'E', 'G'], ['D']]
[['A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'E', 'D'], ['G']]
[['A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'G', 'D'], ['E']]
[['A', 'C', 'F'], ['E', 'G', 'D'], ['B']]
[['A', 'C', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['D']]
[['A', 'C', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'D'], ['F']]
[['A', 'C', 'G'], ['B', 'F', 'D'], ['E']]
[['A', 'C', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'D'], ['B']]
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C', 'G'], ['F']]
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C', 'F'], ['G']]
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'G', 'F'], ['C']]
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'G', 'F'], ['B']]
[['A', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'E', 'C'], ['G']]
[['A', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'E', 'G'], ['C']]
[['A', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'G'], ['E']]
[['A', 'D', 'F'], ['E', 'C', 'G'], ['B']]
[['A', 'D', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'C'], ['F']]
[['A', 'D', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['C']]
[['A', 'D', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'F'], ['E']]
[['A', 'D', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'F'], ['B']]
[['A', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'G'], ['D']]
[['A', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['G']]
[['A', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'G', 'D'], ['C']]
[['A', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'G', 'D'], ['B']]
[['A', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'F'], ['D']]
[['A', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['F']]
[['A', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'F', 'D'], ['C']]
[['A', 'E', 'G'], ['C', 'F', 'D'], ['B']]
[['A', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'C'], ['D']]
[['A', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'D'], ['C']]
[['A', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E']]
[['A', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'D'], ['B']]
[['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'A', 'G'], ['F']]
[['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'A', 'F'], ['G']]
[['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'G', 'F'], ['A']]
[['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'G', 'F'], ['E']]
[['B', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'G', 'F'], ['D']]
[['B', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'G', 'D'], ['F']]
[['B', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'F', 'D'], ['G']]
[['B', 'C', 'E'], ['G', 'F', 'D'], ['A']]
[['B', 'C', 'F'], ['E', 'A', 'G'], ['D']]
[['B', 'C', 'F'], ['E', 'A', 'D'], ['G']]
[['B', 'C', 'F'], ['E', 'G', 'D'], ['A']]
[['B', 'C', 'F'], ['A', 'G', 'D'], ['E']]
[['B', 'C', 'G'], ['E', 'A', 'F'], ['D']]
[['B', 'C', 'G'], ['E', 'A', 'D'], ['F']]
[['B', 'C', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'D'], ['A']]
[['B', 'C', 'G'], ['A', 'F', 'D'], ['E']]
[['B', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'A', 'G'], ['F']]
[['B', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'A', 'F'], ['G']]
[['B', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'G', 'F'], ['A']]
[['B', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'G', 'F'], ['C']]
[['B', 'D', 'F'], ['E', 'C', 'A'], ['G']]
[['B', 'D', 'F'], ['E', 'C', 'G'], ['A']]
[['B', 'D', 'F'], ['E', 'A', 'G'], ['C']]
[['B', 'D', 'F'], ['C', 'A', 'G'], ['E']]
[['B', 'D', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'A'], ['F']]
[['B', 'D', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'F'], ['A']]
[['B', 'D', 'G'], ['E', 'A', 'F'], ['C']]
[['B', 'D', 'G'], ['C', 'A', 'F'], ['E']]
[['B', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'A', 'G'], ['D']]
[['B', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'A', 'D'], ['G']]
[['B', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'G', 'D'], ['A']]
[['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G', 'D'], ['C']]
[['B', 'E', 'G'], ['C', 'A', 'F'], ['D']]
[['B', 'E', 'G'], ['C', 'A', 'D'], ['F']]
[['B', 'E', 'G'], ['C', 'F', 'D'], ['A']]
[['B', 'E', 'G'], ['A', 'F', 'D'], ['C']]
[['B', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'A'], ['D']]
[['B', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'D'], ['A']]
[['B', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'A', 'D'], ['C']]
[['B', 'F', 'G'], ['C', 'A', 'D'], ['E']]
[['C', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'A', 'G'], ['F']]
[['C', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'A', 'F'], ['G']]
[['C', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'G', 'F'], ['A']]
[['C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'G', 'F'], ['B']]
[['C', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'E', 'A'], ['G']]
[['C', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'E', 'G'], ['A']]
[['C', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'A', 'G'], ['E']]
[['C', 'D', 'F'], ['E', 'A', 'G'], ['B']]
[['C', 'D', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'A'], ['F']]
[['C', 'D', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A']]
[['C', 'D', 'G'], ['B', 'A', 'F'], ['E']]
[['C', 'D', 'G'], ['E', 'A', 'F'], ['B']]
[['C', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'A', 'G'], ['D']]
[['C', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'A', 'D'], ['G']]
[['C', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'G', 'D'], ['A']]
[['C', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G', 'D'], ['B']]
[['C', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'A', 'F'], ['D']]
[['C', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'A', 'D'], ['F']]
[['C', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'F', 'D'], ['A']]
[['C', 'E', 'G'], ['A', 'F', 'D'], ['B']]
[['C', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'A'], ['D']]
[['C', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'D'], ['A']]
[['C', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'A', 'D'], ['E']]
[['C', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'A', 'D'], ['B']]
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'A'], ['G']]
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'G'], ['A']]
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'A', 'G'], ['C']]
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'A', 'G'], ['B']]
[['D', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'A'], ['F']]
[['D', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'F'], ['A']]
[['D', 'E', 'G'], ['B', 'A', 'F'], ['C']]
[['D', 'E', 'G'], ['C', 'A', 'F'], ['B']]
[['D', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'C'], ['A']]
[['D', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'A'], ['C']]
[['D', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'A'], ['E']]
[['D', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'C', 'A'], ['B']]
[['E', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'A'], ['D']]
[['E', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A']]
[['E', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'A', 'D'], ['C']]
[['E', 'F', 'G'], ['C', 'A', 'D'], ['B']]
```

Comment: Would this work for larger lists i.e when **len(list_of_ppl) > 10** and when len(list_of_ppl) is not divisible by 3?

Comment: Yes, you simply would have to adjust the number `3` in my answer to half of the length of `list_of_ppl` (`len(list_of_ppl) // 2`).

Comment: I only want a team of `3`, but my input list can be larger than 6 and can be of length that is not divisible 3.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with a solution for your new requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This was exactly what I was looking for ! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `combinations` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations
list(map(list,combinations(list_of_ppl,3)))

[['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'E'],
 ['A', 'B', 'F'],
 ['A', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'C', 'E'],
 ['A', 'C', 'F'],
 ['A', 'D', 'E'],
 ['A', 'D', 'F'],
 ['A', 'E', 'F'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['B', 'C', 'E'],
 ['B', 'C', 'F'],
 ['B', 'D', 'E'],
 ['B', 'D', 'F'],
 ['B', 'E', 'F'],
 ['C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['C', 'D', 'F'],
 ['C', 'E', 'F'],
 ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Or:

```
l = list(map(list,combinations(list_of_ppl,3)))
list(map(list,zip(l[::2],l[::-1][::2])))

[[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']],
 [['A', 'B', 'E'], ['C', 'D', 'F']],
 [['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E', 'F']],
 [['A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'D', 'E']],
 [['A', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'E']],
 [['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'E', 'F']],
 [['B', 'C', 'F'], ['A', 'D', 'E']],
 [['B', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'E']],
 [['C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'F']],
 [['C', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]]
```

Or:

```
list(map(list,zip(l,l[::-1])))

[[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']],
 [['A', 'B', 'D'], ['C', 'E', 'F']],
 [['A', 'B', 'E'], ['C', 'D', 'F']],
 [['A', 'B', 'F'], ['C', 'D', 'E']],
 [['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E', 'F']],
 [['A', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'D', 'F']],
 [['A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'D', 'E']],
 [['A', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C', 'F']],
 [['A', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'E']],
 [['A', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'D']],
 [['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'E', 'F']],
 [['B', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'D', 'F']],
 [['B', 'C', 'F'], ['A', 'D', 'E']],
 [['B', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'F']],
 [['B', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'E']],
 [['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'D']],
 [['C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'F']],
 [['C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'E']],
 [['C', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D']],
 [['D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]]
```

---

```
for v in list(map(list,zip(l,l[::-1]))):
    print(v)

[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['C', 'E', 'F']]
[['A', 'B', 'E'], ['C', 'D', 'F']]
[['A', 'B', 'F'], ['C', 'D', 'E']]
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E', 'F']]
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'D', 'F']]
[['A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'D', 'E']]
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C', 'F']]
[['A', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'E']]
[['A', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'D']]
[['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'E', 'F']]
[['B', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'D', 'F']]
[['B', 'C', 'F'], ['A', 'D', 'E']]
[['B', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'F']]
[['B', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'E']]
[['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'D']]
[['C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'F']]
[['C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'E']]
[['C', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: This doesn't generalize well and it's not remotely clear why pairing up the `combinations` results in this particular way actually finds the proper "complement" values.

Answer (score 0):

the built-in itertools has a helper function for doing it.
`itertools.combinations`

[see doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20combinations#itertools.combinations)

> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input >iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.